# PHP How to upload image from popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup

I want to upload image from popup but not getting proper solution.

**what i wanted to do**
1. On button click open popup
2. In that popup open form for browse image
3. After uploading image i want to show image in same popup and user can crop it
4. After completed cropping save image to database and folder and want to show profile pic

**What i did**
1.I have completed all code in core php but without using popup

*for popup*
2. I can open popup on button click, browse file and action goes to controller.

**Code** 
*View page*

```
 // open popup
    <div class="profile-pic fl">
        <div class="txtc">
            <?php  echo $this->tag->image(array("img/profile_pic_default.jpg","class"=>"profile_img")) ; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="txtc mrgt2">
            <button  id="openPopup" onclick="upload_action();">Upload Image</button>
        </div>
    </div>

 //iamge upload form

<div id="up-image" style="display: none">
<div style="margin:0 auto; width:600px">
    <div id="thumbs" style="padding:5px; width:600px"></div>
    <div id="crop-image" style="width:600px">
        <?php echo $this->tag->form(array("personaldetails/uploadImage","id"=>"cropimage",'enctype'=>"multipart/form-data"))?>
            Upload your image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script to open popup and send data**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $edit_dialog = $("#up-image").dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        title:"Upload image",
        modal:true,
        height: 300,
        width: 600,
        buttons:[
            {text: "Submit", click: function() { $('form',$(this)).submit(); }},
            {text: "Cancel", click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }}
        ],
        create: function(event, ui)
        {
            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("margin-left", 350);
            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("margin-top", 50);

        }
    });

    //Submit action for dialog form
    $("#up-image form").submit(function() {
        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(),function(formData)
        {
            alert('done'+data);
            $("#up-image").dialog('close');
        },'json');

        //stop default form submit action
        return false;
    });
    //attach action to edit links
});

function upload_action()
{
    $edit_dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

**Controller action**

```
public function uploadImageAction()
{
    echo "<pre>";print_r($_FILES);echo "<pre>";exit; // not able to get request 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jcrop plugin for that:

http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos/crop.php

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

For fullfill your requirement you have to use:
AjaxUpload and JCrop together.

Ajaxupload will upload image to server and jcrop helps you to crop image.

After croppping you have to need old image and save cropped image in DB and folder.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply i have code to do above things as you mentioned but i want to do this using popup.

Comment: first thing you can't get $_FILES in AJAX($.post, $.get or $.ajax), so you have to upload file using ajaxupload and after upload it show user that image and give option to crop that image.

Answer (score 0):

add form in  a hidden div and set position absolute or fixed

animate or fade in hidden div on-clik  function

set z-index for div ordering

Comment: Thanks for your help but i can open popup, in that popup i can open form to upload file but i am not able to get form values on controller action

Comment: use ajax file uploader